How do we handle legitimate answer posts that use "free" add-ons if the user can later change the price?
There is a legit answer post here by @shico (same as the previously deleted by moderator) that claims to use a free add-on with step-by-step instructions, but when I checked, it was \$3 so I commented the following:

The community generally focuses on providing solutions using Blender’s
built-in features and FREE add-ons. Paid add-ons are not typically
used as default solutions unless they are specifically mentioned by
the person asking the question


But then the user decided to make it free and changed the price to \$0+ because he noticed it was being reviewed by the community. Since it was recently changed, it is still displaying the cached previous \$3 price. Anyway, the real issue is that after the review, he can easily change the add-on price back to $3+ or more, making it no longer free and no longer a valid answer. How do we deal with these posts?
But it can also be argued that the post can remain, even if using a paid addon, since it's better than having no answers at all on this question. Or should they be taken down once the user changes the price again but how do we keep track that he changed the price to greater than 0? It's tricky because the link can become "invalid" once it changes to not being free.
But even if I was mistaken about this product and it is really \$0 but just erroneously got displayed for \$3, it is still a theoretical scenario or not?

Disregarding the paid/ free content question (which is interesting in its own right and I don't have anything to add to the answers) I just have this to say about the €3 / €0 discrepancy, I think it's something specific to gumroad, the file is free (see the €0 mark in the left of the page) but €3 is a suggested fair price (the amount might be set by the author), and lightly greyed out to not make it stand out too much. You can input 0 in the field and it works. Whether it is a fair market practice is up for debate, but I don't think the intention here was to force users to pay for it. Cheers

Also do keep in mind that on gumroad and any other site, free items are not free, you are paying with your e-mail address information ;)

Thanks for bringing this up.
Questions about addons on our site have been raised several times before and all came to the same conclusion so far.

How should we handle questions about addons?

Are questions about third party paid addons on topic?

Concerning third-party addons and question closing


My stance on this remains unaltered, and aligns with what has been answered before.
Questions about and answers relying on third party (payed or free) addons, are on topic and welcome here.
This site is for all things Blender related, as long as they remain on topic according to out rules. Some additional rules apply though.

Any answers involving payed addons must clearly disclose that the solution involves a commercial addon in the beginning of the post
The poster must disclose any affiliation with said commercial product (i.e. he is the author, co-creator, developer, promoter, affiliate, etc), if any
The answer must make a genuine attempt at solving the issue
The solution must be thoroughly explained and present clear steps to follow.
The post must not read like an advertisement, nor otherwise exist solely for the purpose of promoting the product (be a valid answer on its own merit)

Likewise questions about third party even commercial addons are on topic, because  Blender is a software that supports addons, and they are a central part of the native functionality. Some third party authors may also intentionally divert support requests for their products to our site, with honest intentions of answering them themselves, with the goal of making them easily accessible. Good examples of this are animation-nodes and upbge.
Whether these posts will be well received or not, is of course a whole other matter. Naturally we would never expect any user to make some purchase to be able to answer some question, so those posts are naturally less likely to get a response, but that is just a fact the posters have to accept.
Answers using third party addons may or may not be well received as well, depending on how clear and well written they are. Obviously using free addons or native functionality is always preferred of course, but that may not always be possible or practical.
Regardless they are still on topic, as long as they follow the rules and clearly disclose the intentions.
Regarding your specific case I'd say it would suffice to mention in the answer that it uses a commercial addon right at the beginning. No mention of price or any other detail that could easily get outdated or require maintenance. That way the user is warned before investing any time reading the answer.
If the user is interested enough he can visit the link and find out about the price (if any) or other information. If it happens to have been made free at some point in time, then a pleasant surprise is preferable than wasting efforts only find there is a pay wall at the end of the road.
Once again this is my stance. If anyone has a different opinion post it as an answer, and let the amount of votes determine a binding decision.

Interesting, I would also lean towards this stance as it makes a lot of sense to me. Thank you for sharing! So since this is the same post it should have not been deleted but just edited to include #1 & #2 as it seems genuine at its attempt to provide a solution. IMHO, #1 Any answers involving payed addons should probably not just be paid addons but for all 3rd party addons as they can change anytime from free to not-free so they should probably all indicate at least point #2

Oh I checked the history of the post and it was a link only answer at time of deletion so it probably was justified to convert to comment

I'd just add the warning on first occurrence of being payed, anything more might unjustly scare off potential users, and adds a lot of maintenance overhead. Addosn even payed one are open source b definition, and lots most remain free indefinitely , seems unnecessary to tag those, unless there is an actual occurrence of being payed

Thanks to @Duarte for such a thorough exposition of what seems to me to be a rational and consistent policy. Personally, I would second that entirely, with perhaps just one further point:
To be in  the spirit of self-contained explanatory SE answers, an add-on linked answer should contain at least a sketch-summary of the strategy the add-on is using to solve the problem. (Not just how to use it.)
That also changes the returned value of any payment for the add-on  from: 'access to proprietary information' to: 'saving the labour of doing it yourself.'
That seems important to me, in an open-source project. I don't know if anybody has any thoughts on that aspect, or the practicality of policing it.

Thank you Robin for sharing your thoughts!

@HarryMcKenzie Not at all. it's a good question, and Duarte has done a great job of laying out a position which we can fairly adopt.

This seems a fair point. I have previously encouraged authors of non commercial addons to include code snippets of any scripts in their answer (if it is single file and short enough), or at least parts of it, to avoid the pitfalls of link only answers (if the links become unavailable, the answer becomes impossible to follow). For commercial ones though, that seems unfair to ask, but a rough explanation of the procedure would be nice to have, in the name of open source. Not sure if I'd enforce this very rigidly, but I'd certainly request politely.
